# Codeigniter 2 project login redirects to a port number - Getting This site can’t be reached

Tags: php, codeigniter, ubuntu, nginx, port

The login page redirects to a page with :8080 port number I'm running ubuntu nginx server for the project I'm i supposed to configure the host file to add the port number or what could be the issue? Thanks

```
<form id="login_form" name="login_form" method="post" class="login-form" action="http://<?php echo $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']; ?>:8080/admin/main/login" >
    <?
    if($check=='wrong')
    {
    ?>
```

[Screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DT1d4.png)

Comment: You've :8080 in the form action!

Comment: Take :8080 out of the form action and you are set

Comment: check out the `url_helper` and `base_url()`. as long as it is set correctly you can do `echo base_url('admin/main/login');` where `'base_url' = "http://localhost";`

Comment: Where do I run the echo string to check?

Comment: When i remove :8080 on the form it's still not working

Comment: Cause it's a project that someone else developed do you know what i can do so that it works with port :8080